# вкладка не на всю высоту

Tags: reactjs, react-native, height

делаю приложение на react native и не получается растянуть элемент на всю высоту (или это какая-то линия). Заранее спасибо [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В стилях `flex: 1` - растянет на всего родителя...

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать Dimensions для получения высоты экрана.
Вот пример использования.

```
const screen = Dimensions.get('window').height;

return (
  <View style={{height: screen - 100}}> 
     введите сюда код
  </View>

)
```

вместо 100 может быть любое другое число